# Restricting OneDrive via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to restrict OneDrive usage on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 Clients

I'm following [an article on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921901.aspx) about this, and says on my 2012 R2 domain controller to modify the GPO under the following:

> In the Group Policy Management Editor, under Computer Configuration, click Policies, click Administrative Templates, click Windows Components, and then click OneDrive.

However, OneDrive doesn't appear.  Any ideas on what I could do here?

Comment: It might be still called SkyDrive if your templates are a bit old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the admin templates for Windows 10 (Windows 8 would also suffice, but since you have Win 10, get the newer ones!).  You will need to install these into the SYSVOL\PolicyDefinitions folder on a DC.

[ADMX download (Microsoft.com)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48257) for Windows 10.